# How to call webservice with post data in android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am not getting any response, what is the problem in my code. Due to privacy policies I am not providing correct URl.

```
public static String URL = "http://www.example.com/web_service/mainAPI.php";
final String body = String.format("rquest={\"method\":\"upcoming_shows\",\"body\":[{}]}");
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upcoming_show);
    try{    
        Log.d("In Try", "Going...");
        final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(URL);
        postMethod.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, "utf-8"));
        final HttpResponse response = client.execute(postMethod);
        final String responseData = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "utf-8");
        Toast.makeText(UpcomingShow.this, responseData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

please give me some solution.

Comment: Debug your code and see where is the problem

Comment: you should not do network related operations on UIThread you should either use asynctask or anyother mechanisms availabe

Comment: I am Toast ResponseData but no data is Toasting. it toast blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are trying to access network on UI thread, thats no longer allowed. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception/6343299#6343299).
2. You probably have a typo in your `String body`, it says `rquest`, I believe it should be `request` (on line 2)